# Let $T^t$ be a linear transformation from $W^* \to V^*$, how do I see this goes into $V^*$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T^t$ be a linear transformation from $W^* \to V^*$, where $T : V\to W$.

I know that $T^t\lambda(v) = \lambda(Tv)$ is the natrually induced transformation but I cant see why this actually takes something from $W^*$ into $V^*$.

I understand that $\lambda\in W^*$ means that $\lambda$ is a linear functional which takes vectors in $W$ to scalars in $F$, and $Tv \in W$ so $\lambda(Tv)$ is something taking an element of $W$ to a scalar in $F$. Where does $V^*$ factor in? $V^*$ are functionals which take vectors in $V$ to scalars in $F$....

Am I missing something blatantly obvious?

Comment: Consider $\lambda\in W^*$, i.e. $\lambda\colon W\to\Bbbk$. For any $T\colon V\to W$, $T^t(\lambda):=\lambda\circ T\colon V\to\Bbbk$, so $T^t(\lambda)\in V^*$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\lambda\in W^\ast$, you want to check if $T^t(\lambda)\in V^\ast$. That is, does $T^t(\lambda)$ send elements of $V$ into $F$? So for $v\in V$, 
$$
T^t(\lambda)(v)=\lambda(Tv)\in F
$$
since $Tv\in W$, and $\lambda$ sends elements of $W$ into $F$.

Answer (score 1):

The dual map $T^t$ **pre-composes** a functional $\lambda \in W^*$ with $T$.  I like to picture it this way:
$$
\big(\, W \overset{\lambda}{\to} F\, \big) \quad \overset{\Large T^t}{\longmapsto} \quad \big(\, V \overset{T}{\to} W \overset{\lambda}{\to} F\, \big)
$$